# Remove all ink from an InkPresenter control

Tags: .net, silverlight

I'm using an InkPresenter control and I've set it up so I can drawn simple black lines on it, with this code:

```
private Stroke newstroke;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    inkP.CaptureMouse();
    newstroke = new Stroke();

    //Add stylus points via Getter-method, use inkP as argument.
    newstroke.StylusPoints.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(inkP));

    //Add captured strokes to canvas.
    inkP.Strokes.Add(newstroke);
}

private void btnUpHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Set stroke object to NULL and stop capturing the mouse.
    newstroke = null;
    inkP.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}

private void mouseMoveHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Check for NULL, see btnUpHandler
    if (newstroke != null) {
        //If not NULL, keep adding stylus points to the Stroke object.
        newstroke.StylusPoints.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(inkP));
    }
}
```

My problem is: I want to implement a button, which I click, and it removes everything that was previously added to the InkPresenter.

I've tried `inkP.Children.Clear();` but that didn't work. I've tried `inkP.Strokes.Remove(newstroke)`. Didn't work either.

Is there no easy function to remove all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `inkP.Strokes.Clear();`, not `Children.Clear();`